# Can IIS Media Services run on IIS Express?

Tags: iis-express

Can I use IIS Express to stream video (by using IIS Media Services, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Express is primarily for local development. probably/theoretically you could run iis media services on IIS Express but there is no UI for configuring it on IIS Express. Take a look at some other limitations of IIS Express [What is to prevent me from using IIS Express exclusively on my development box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317209/what-is-to-prevent-me-from-using-iis-express-exclusively-on-my-development-box/5317698#5317698)